# Error in listing data on a javascript/html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this javascript that is taking data in from a fusion table and listing on a html document, the error I am getting is located in this line:

```
<a href="data[row][4]">" + data[row][4] + "</a>\
```

I honestly have zero idea as to what is causing the error so I have come to you guys. The data is a web address and I need it to be clickable. If you have any insight in a way to fix this or get around it, it would be greatly appreciated.
:)

I have posted the rest of the section of code it is attached to below.

```
MapsLib.prototype.displayList = function(json) {
    var self = this;
var data = json['rows'];
var template = '';

var results = $('#results_list');
results.hide().empty(); //hide the existing list and empty it out first

if (data == null) {
  //clear results list
  results.append("<li><span class='lead'>No results found</span></li>");
}
else {
  for (var row in data) {
    template = "\
      <div class='row-fluid item-list'>\
        <div class='span12'>\
          <strong>" + data[row][0] + "</strong><spacer> --- </spacer><strong2>" + data[row][1] + "</strong2>\
          <br />\
          <suburb>" + data[row][2] + "</suburb>\
          <br />\
          " + data[row][3] + "\
          <br />\
          <a href="data[row][4]">" + data[row][4] + "</a>\
          <br />\
          " + data[row][5] + "\
          <br />\
          " + data[row][6] + "\
          <br />\
          " + data[row][7] + "\
        </div>\
      </div>";
    results.append(template);
  }
}
results.fadeIn();
},
```

Comment: Please show the error.

Comment: Try this:
<a href=' " + data[row][4] + " '>" + data[row][4] + "</a>\

Comment: Armen, thankyou so much! How do I show yours as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

"href" is to navigate the url...
this is not a correct path= "data[row][4]">" + data[row][4] + "
if you want to call any function use onclick....